# Scipy replacement for phased decoder

Tags: python, linux, scipy

I am running a phased decoder written in Python on certain audio files to decrypt messages. When processing the audio file, which was not made by me, I am told there is no module named Scipy to import.

I cannot install new Python modules on the system I am using. Is there any way to make a phased decoder without using external modules such as Scipy? If it helps I already have Numpy installed on the system.

Comment: for that specific software you do need scipy, you can try installing it in a conda environment, maybe that works with your network, you could also run it in a google colab instance that should work fine.

Comment: Are you not able to create a virtualenv inside your local linux folder? Then you could install scipy into that venv